# PHP issue passing results of variables from one function to another in same file but works on other pages

Tags: php

I am having an issue accessing my global variables inside the same file where the variables exist. However, they work just fine when I call the same variable in other files. To call the variable in another file I have used the `required_once` to call my file where the globals are located and then called each variable I need individually like  `global $example_vairable`.

The issue is that when I use  `global $example_vairable` later on in the same file where I defined  `global $example_vairable` it does not work. Inside of another function on the same page I have called my variable  `global $example_vairable` and then just tested with either an `echo` or a `var_dump`. `echo` shows no display and `var_dump` provides a `bool(false)`  telling me I have an error but I have no idea where or why.

This is in wordpress so I am using my functions file where my variables are located. Here is my code:

THE FUNCTIONS FILE GLOBAL VAIRABLE

```
function Total_Result(){
    global $total_result, $resultx;

     $resultxs = array($resultx);
     $total_result =  count($resultxs[0]);
    //return($total_result);
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'Total_Result' );
```

Then the function on the same file (functions.php) that I am trying to call the global from:

```
add_action("wp_ajax_getvendorresponsestatus", "getvendorresponsestatus");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_getvendorresponsestatus", "getvendorresponsestatus");

function getvendorresponsestatus() {
    global $wpdb, $endResult,$total_result ;
    if(isset($_POST['action']) == 'getvendorresponsestatus'){

                    echo $total_result;
        var_dump($total_result);
            var_dump($endResult);
            echo $endResult->posted_by;
        

};
}
```

I have also tried to pass the variable in the function itself but it too doesnt work.

```
add_action("wp_ajax_getvendorresponsestatus", "getvendorresponsestatus");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_getvendorresponsestatus", "getvendorresponsestatus");

function getvendorresponsestatus($endResult, $total_result) {
    global $wpdb;
    if(isset($_POST['action']) == 'getvendorresponsestatus'){

                    echo $total_result;
        var_dump($total_result);
            var_dump($endResult);
            echo $endResult->posted_by;
        

};
}
```

Comment: I suspect this is a common misunderstanding for developers new to PHP. Global variables do not carry over from one request to another. PHP is not like Node applications, every request loads WordPress from a blank slate. Only data stored files and the database survives from one request to another.

Comment: okt hen what is the solution and why does it work on remote pages?

Comment: If your question does not get the response you desire, you should edit and improve it, instead of deleting it and asking it again a day later. I've marked this as a duplicate of your new question as the new question contains more code and information